# How to design a junction table in a many to many relationship with potentially non unique rows

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I am designing a home database for sensors placed around the house in different rooms.  I have mapped out the database so far as follows:

```
tbl_floor = id, name - (e.g 1, first)
tbl_room = id, floor_id, name - (e.g 1, 1, lounge)
tbl_sensortype = id, name - e.g (1, dht11)
tbl_measurementtype = id, name - e.g (1, temperature)
```

There is a many to many relationship between sensor and measurement (e.g dht11 can do temp and humidity), therefore I have a junction table:

```
tbl_sensortype_measurementtype = id, sensortype_id, measurementtype_id - (e.g 1, 1, 1) for a dht11 sensor's temperature measurement (it does other things too)
```

Now comes my question:

Each room could potentially have multiple sensors of the same type (e.g one room has a terrarrium with a temperature sensor and a room temperature sensor).  So there is a many to many relationship between the tables tbl_room and tbl_sensortype_measurementtype but this could lead to non-unique rows in the junction table:

```
tbl_room_sensortype_measurementtype = room_id, sensortype_measurementtype_id - (e.g 1, 1) is a dht11 sensor's temperature measurement in the lounge
```

But a second dht11 sensor would have the same row if placed in the same room.

I could put an id in the junction table which then makes it unique but it is hard to distinguish between them, i.e

```
tbl_room_sensortype_measurementtype = id, room_id, sensortype_measurementtype_id
```

Would it therefore be sensible (acceptable from a design perspective) to include another column in this junction table called "instance" so that I can easily distinguish between the two sensors of the same type in the same room? or is there a better/more preferable way? i.e my junction table would be defined as:

```
tbl_room_sensortype_measurementtype = id, room_id, sensortype_measurementtype_id, instance
```

Then when I wanted to log a value from a sensor my value table would be defined as:

```
tbl_values = room_sensortype_measurementtype_id, value, time
```

I hope my question makes sense (I am learning db design as a "fun" project).
Thank you,
Martyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a new table instead of `tbl_room_sensortype_measurementtype` that maps between room and its sensors like below,

```
tbl_sensor_room = id, room_id, sensortype_id
```

Here each sensor will have a unique `id` despite the same room and sensor type. This table can be later joined with `tbl_sensortype_measurementtype` in SQL to get the measurement types.

`instance` becomes a redundant column in terms of uniqueness since it is already captured by `id`. One can write SQL queries using `id` to achieve any desired result without `instance`. From design perspective, unless there are SQL queries that can benefit in terms of speed from directly querying `instance` column like querying for 1st instance for a room etc., there is no need to have it.

Comment: Thank you Shiram, but would it be okay to put another column in that table called instance to help me to distinguish the two sensors in the same room?

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I am just thinking ahead.  If I have two identical sensors in the same room I see that id distinguishes them and makes them unique from a design perspective.  Would I assign the id rather than using autoincrement? This would allow me to easily distinguish between sensor 1 and sensor 2.  e.g two rows could be (1,1,1) and (2,1,1).   My reasoning behind the table tbl_room_sensortype_measurementtype was that it would mean that I would only have fewer columns in my data table whereas if I went with tbl_sensor_room I would need an extra column in my table

Comment: I ran out of space: the data table would need sensor_room_id, measurement_type_id, value, timestamp.  Is this more preferable?  Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Hi again, I have added some changes to my original question based on your helpful response.  It has, however, thrown up some more questions.  Thanks, Martyn

Comment: Gordon, very sorry.  I will remove my changes.